# FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/java/jdbc__init.class

Tags: jar, clojure, namespaces, require

I have a problem with importing jars in clojure.
I used lein to add dependencies.
This is code from project.clj

```
(defproject recommendation "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "FIXME: write description"
:url "http://example.com/FIXME"
     :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
      :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
      :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                     [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.0.6"]         ;; jdbc 
                     [mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.6"]]
  :aot :all
  :main recommendation.core)
```

I typed in the command `lein deps`, and it downloaded 3 jars in lib folder.

This is code from recommendation.core

> (ns recommendation.core
>         (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as sql])   )

And I get exception:

```
FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/java/jdbc__init.class or clojure/java/jdbc.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)
```

Can anybody tell me where i am wrong and what to do?

Comment: i have tried with "0.3.0-alpha4", and it is the same.

Answer (score 4):

here's my dependency line:

```
[org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.2.3"]
```

Heres the require line from one of my projects that use jdbc

```
(:require [clojure.java [jdbc :as sql]])
```

If none of this helps here are my standard leiningen fixing steps:

1. lein deps and look for errors
2. lein clean
3. lein upgrade
4. lein deps :tree and look for strangeness
5. rm -rf target/ # this one has only helped me with messed up native deps.
6. rm ~/.m2/repository -rf # this is the last resort, it's lots of downloading.
7. join #leiningen on irc.freenode.net and ask for help

PS: I found [this video](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Clojure-Namespaces-Vars-Symbols) helpful in getting a handle on namespaces.

Comment: Just `(:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as sql])` also works. You rarely want to do the nested vector syntax. It tends to make things difficult to read.

Comment: i am getting the same error. I dont know what is wrong, is it version of jar, or i missed some step to include that jar in project. When i type lein classpath, i see that jar in lib folder..

Answer (score 0):

update the dependencies line to the latest jdbc.java version:
https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc

at the time of writing it is version 0.7.3:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]  [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.7.3"]]
```